# database table access from two difference parts

Tags: database, database-design

We have an in house standalone application which will not connect to the internet and not a client-server type. We have no plan to use any application server for now.

There are two components, one is ours, one is from client, in our application need to access the same database. We may use MySQL or Oracle database.

Most of the data are not shared. But we do have few of them are shared between us. if both side read those data, it will be fine. If one of us is trying to write, I think we need to do something then. I am thinking the table level sychronization. Does database itself provide some mechanism to sychronize them? What we should do and where and how?

Comment: Both Oracle and MySQL will organize things so that concurrent access by applications will be properly managed (for slightly different but reasonable definitions of properly managed).

Comment: So we don't need to worry about it and concurrent write in table level will not be allowed?

Comment: No it will not be just blanket disallowed. Writing to _different_ rows of the same table will be allowed and will be done concurrently. Writing to the same row will invoke some form of concurrency control such as locking. But this is not your question, I assume? You are actually asking what to do if one client caches the table and another client writes in that table "behind first client's back", correct?